# I can't get the "tool options" window to reconnect to the "toolbox" window. Dragging and dropping doesn't work

Tags: gimp, toolbar

So I use gimp for sketching and such and I can't seem to get the tool options window to reconnect with the toolbar :/ I've tried to drag and drop it but it doesn't do anything. Please help :c

Comment: Open the "Windows" menu and select "Single-Window Mode"

Answer (score 0):

Dragging and dropping does work. A common error is to drag the detached Tool option by its title bar. You have to drag it by its tab (exactly like you would drag tabs across Firefox or Chrome windows).
[image]

Comment: There are a few known applications that meddle with drag and drop in GTK+ applications - among others, that is Skype, Kaspersky Antivirus, Camtasia, Snagit,  Camstudio, Tuneup Utilities. Although this probably can and has to be fixed in GTK, no place where to start from has been determined yet. The maintainers of the applications mentioned either won't reply to inquiries, or are unable to provide information that would be helpful.